# Book where orphans die and go to another kingdom

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I'm seeking a book I read as a kid in the 80s about two orphans who were (I think) in the foster system. Brother and sister. He always told her tales of a magical land with a name that I think began with *Nangri*-something or similar.
One day there waas a fire and they died, possibly him before her. Awakening, they were in that kingdom of *Nangriwhatsit*.

They went on to have heroic adventures before dying again and as they lay dying, he began telling her stories of the next kingdom they would arrive in...

Comment: Thank you - That is exactly it - I am in your debt forever!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[*The Brothers Lionheart*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/19312.The_Brothers_Lionheart) by Astrid Lindgren.

> There's no one Karl Lion loves more than his older brother, Jonathan, who is brave, strong, and handsome - everything Karl believes he is not. Karl never wants to be parted from him. But Karl is sick, and knows he's going to die. To comfort him, Jonathan tells him stories of Nangiyala, the wonderful place he'll be going to when he dies, and where he will wait until Jonathan is ready to join him there.
>
> Then the unthinkable happens . . . Jonathan is killed in an accident. Heartbroken, Karl longs for the day he'll be reunited with his brother. When the time comes, he finds Nangiyala just as wonderful as he'd imagined. However, Nangiyala is under threat. A cruel tyrant is determined to claim it as his own, and at his command is a terrible beast that is feared throughout the land.
>
> Karl must summon all of his courage to help his brother prepare for the battle that lies ahead.

Comment: All makt åt Tengil, vår befriare!

Comment: Does anybody know if Lindgren was familiar with the works of C.S. Lewis?